# HttpHostConnectException when Validating Account in Creation of IBM Bluemix Server

Tags: eclipse, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

> Unable to communicate with server - I/O error on GET request for "https://api.ng.bluemix.net/info":Connect to 10.81.82.132:80 [/10.81.82.132] failed: Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 10.81.82.132:80 [/10.81.82.132] failed: Connection timed out: connect

I am getting this error when trying to create a Bluemix server in Eclipse, specifically on click of Validate Account button. I have downloaded and installed the IBM Bluemix for Eclipse plug-in but still having connectivity issues. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The connection error is depending from the wrong IP address your internet ISP/provider is returning for api.ng.bluemix.net

Check your DNS configuration, you could run the following command

```
nslookup api.ng.bluemix.net
```

to check which DNS server is returning the wrong IP address.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I have run the nslookup command and it returns with the IP Address  75.126.70.44. Strangely, the connection was working a week back, I opened Eclipse a week after and I see this error.